# django rest framework serialize property field as date?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this :

```
extra_kwargs = {
    'posting_date': {'format':'%d-%m-%Y'},
    'validation_date': {'format':'%d-%m-%Y'},
    'execution_date': {'format':'%d-%m-%Y'},
    'rejection_date': {'format':'%d-%m-%Y'},
    'deadline': {'format':'%d-%m-%Y'}
}
```

Every thing works fine with first 4 fields since they are datetime django model field. the last one (deadline) is a property and It's not treated as datetime by django serializer even if it returns a datetime so using format raises an exception.

Any solution for this issue ?

Comment: What do you mean by `(deadline) is a property`?

Comment: python property defined in the model associated to this serializer (link for python properties https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property)

Comment: OK. Then see my answer below. Before declaring `extra_kwargs`, convert `deadline` into a `datetime` obj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override to_representation method to reformat response data

Answer (score 0):

You can always convert a string to a python `datetime` object, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

# strptime stands for "from string parse the (date)time"
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime('Jan 30 2017 17:00PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
```

More on this [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

Comment: yes but when to write this and how to link it with deadline property field. finally I have found one solution to override to_presentation method by calling super and updating deadline field using strptime thank you